# not able to generate correlated variables by cholesky decomposition due to negative definiteness

Tags: r, simulation, correlation

I want to generate 3 variables, x1, x2, x3, where x1 is highly correlated with x2 an x3, but x2 and x3 are uncorrelated. The correlation matrix is, say，

```
corr= (1, 0.8, 0.8，

       0.8, 1, 0，

       0.8, 0, 1)
```

But this can not be done by cholesky decomposition, as the theory shows, which you can find here: http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2012/09/12/when-is-a-correlation-matrix-not-a-correlation-matrix/

Is there any alternative and simple way to do it? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Could you clarify: are you trying to generate a complete dataset with correlation properties you know are theoretically impossible to have? ahum... (notice that you can also trivially generate an incomplete dataset with a lot of *NA* values that will achieve your correlation matrix if you choose a NA-friendly way of computing the correlation matrix).

Comment: It can not be done because the correlation matrix is not positive definite but negative definite (with a negative eigenvalue). And a negative definite matrix can not be cholesky deomposed. So we can not generate the variables by cholesky decomposition. And I do want to have a complete data set.

Comment: Do you need a correlation matrix like the example you provide? Can it have a different structure?

Comment: It is OK to inflate the zeros a bit, but not more than 0.1

Comment: Change the 0.8 to 0.7 and you can use `mvrnorm` from the `mvtnorm` library to generate values from a multivariate normal.

Comment: if all 0.8 are changed to 0.7, then a cholesky decomposition will also work because 0.7^2 + 0.7^2 +0^2 - 0 = 0.98 < 1.